# Lightweight migration doesnt work

Tags: xcode, core-data, data-migration

I am working on my app and from 1.0 version I added new attributes to entity in core data. So I added new model version, I set up storeURL to `Model 6.sqlite` (before Model 5.sqlite) after than edit `persistentStoreCoordinator`. But when I run app it crash and log show me error. When I delete app and then install again it works fine. Where can be the problem my app working than hasPerformedFirstLaunch is false initial core data, but I dont wanna lose data every new model version.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty
>   array'

```
NSDictionary *migrateOptions = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption,
                                [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];
```

Comment: If you break on the exception and bring up the backtrace, what does it say?

Comment: App crash when my core data is empty and it show me error up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be missing something here but what was the need to have a new Model 6.sqlite file. You do not need to have a new persistence store file just because you add a new model version. That's what the migration does, to make the existing persistence store compatible with a new model version.

Comment: Thank you I rewrite storeURL, but now it is working.